# How do I move a bitmap Imageview with Xml Buttons?

Tags: android

I'm working on a little side app, and I want it so that when I press a button, the Imageview moves left, and when I press another button, the Imageview moves right

I've tried looking at some tutorials, but they either tell me how to drag an image, or make it move automatically. 
Button Code

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/Left"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="536dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="147dp"
    android:text="Move Left"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.53" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/left2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="536dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="61dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="61dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="147dp"
    android:text="Move Right"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.53" />
```

Comment: You wouldn't do that in xml.  You'd do that in Java.

Comment: Ok, I saw a few tutorials using xml though.

Comment: You'd use XML to define your layout.  Moving things would happen in Java.  Most Android apps contains a mix of each.  You could do it all in xml if you're using databinding, but that's a decision that will totally control all of your architectural decisions for the app, and I see no clue in your existing xml you're doing that.